Save large PDF file with UIDocument
I'm working with UIDocument to store a PDF file. This is code I use for saving a file.
Firstly, I created a document with URL.
let document = UIDocument(fileURL: url)

Second, I opened a document.
document.open(completionHandler: { (success) in
            if success {
                // open successfully
            }
        })

And finally, I saved the document.
document.close(completionHandler: { (success) in
            if success {
                document.save(to: url,
                              for: .forOverwriting,
                              completionHandler: { (success) in
                    if success {
                        print("Saved file successfully")
                    }
                })
            } 
        })

This code works well with a small file size. But if it's a large file like 100MB, it takes around 2-5 minutes to save the file. Is there a way to save file with the changes only? Or create an auto save function triggered whenever the user edit the file?
I tried to find other UIDocument.SaveOperation but seems there're only 2 options: create a new one or overwrite the old file which doesn't match my expectation.

I think in a case we're writing an entire new file, this method is acceptable. But the UIDocument opens a PDF file and let the user edit it, no matter how big or tiny the update is, we still need rewrite the entire file. From user's POV they need to wait 2-5 minutes to actually see the update from a 100MB file which is abnormal. I'm seeking for a method that can update the only needed data.
